# Usar variable de html como parámetro en ts (Angular)

Tags: html, typescript, angular, template, component

Tengo el siguiente código en **html**

```
<li *ngFor="let center of costCenter; let i=index">
<div class="col s4 cCost">
    <p class="centerCost">COST CENTER</p>
    <p-dropdown [options]="costCenter" [(ngModel)]="selectedCostCenter" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
</div>
<div class="col s4 porc">
    <p class="porcentage">PORCENTAGE</p>
    <input class="porcentageInput" id="input">
</div>
<div class="col s2">
    <button mz-button (click)="addCostCenter(i)">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="col s2">
    <button mz-button (click)= "removeCostCenter(i)">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Quiero con, `removeCostCenter`, borrar el array seleccionado. En estos momentos; estoy borrando el último array. Así lo tengo en el ts

```
 removeCostCenter() { 
if (this.costCenter[+1]) {
  let pos = this.costCenter.indexOf(name);
  this.costCenter.splice(pos, 1);
} 
else {
  this.costCenter.splice(1);
}
 }
```

Quiero borrar el array al cual le de click con mi botón; para ello, creo que necesito enviar i  algún método del componente, donde lo necesite usar como parametro. Por favo, me podrían ayudar!

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo tienes casi hecho!

Ya has añadido el índice en la plantilla, sólo tienes que añadirlo como parámetro en el método:

```
removeConstCenter(index: number) {
  if (this.costCenter[index]) {
    this.constCenter.splice(index,1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sií; está bien... También descubrí que se puede hacer de esta manera

removeConstCenter(index: number) {
if ( this.costCenter.length > 1) {
     this.costCenter.splice(i, 1);
}
}

Comment: Como i sea mayor que length, fallará